# Automapper overwrites missing source property on list with child objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a problem with Automapper. I set up a test windows form application and below is the code. Also look at the comments after each MessageBox:

```
public class FirstClass
    {
        public string FirstProp { get; set; }
        public IList<FirstClassChild> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class FirstClassChild
    {
        public string FirstChildProp { get; set; }
    }

    public class SecondClass
    {
        public string FirstProp { get; set; }
        public string SecondProp { get; set; }
        public IList<SecondClassChild> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class SecondClassChild
    {
        public string FirstChildProp { get; set; }
        public string SecondChildProp { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<FirstClass, SecondClass>();
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<FirstClassChild, SecondClassChild>();

            var f = new FirstClass { FirstProp = "FirstClass" };
            f.Children = new List<FirstClassChild> { new FirstClassChild { FirstChildProp = "FirstClass" } };
            var s = new SecondClass { FirstProp = "SecondClass", SecondProp = "SecondClass" };
            s.Children = new List<SecondClassChild> { new SecondClassChild { FirstChildProp = "SecondClass", SecondChildProp = "SecondClass" } };
            AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(f, s);

            var fc = new FirstClassChild { FirstChildProp = "FirstClass" };
            var sc = new SecondClassChild { FirstChildProp = "SecondClass", SecondChildProp = "SecondClass" };
            AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(fc, sc);

            MessageBox.Show(sc.FirstChildProp);//FirstClass as expected
            MessageBox.Show(sc.SecondChildProp);//SecondClass as expected

            MessageBox.Show(s.FirstProp);//FirstClass as expected
            MessageBox.Show(s.SecondProp);//SecondClass as expected
            MessageBox.Show(s.Children.First().FirstChildProp);//FirstClass as expected
            MessageBox.Show(s.Children.First().SecondChildProp);//Empty not expected!!

        }
    }
```

What can I do to avoid this? Is this behavior expected?
Anyway can anyone guide me how make SecondClass childs SecondChildProp to remain "SecondClass" as it is before the mapping occurs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229798/) and found another similar one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724901/).

I think @PatrickSteele makes a very good point:  how is AutoMapper supposed to map a source list to a dest list **of existing objects**, when the dest list may not necessarily bear any resemblance to the source list? i.e.  "[But what if one list has 3 and the other list has 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724901/)"

**If** you are sure that `FirstClass` and `SecondClass` have the same number of `Children`, and **if** the `FirstClass`'s Nth Child always corresponds to `SecondClass`'s Nth child, you could try something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FirstClass, SecondClass>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Children, o => o.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < dest.Children.Count; i++)
                Mapper.Map(src.Children[i], dest.Children[i]);
        });
```

or if `FirstChildProp` is some kind of unique key:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FirstClass, SecondClass>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Children, o => o.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
        {
            foreach (var dChild in dest.Children)
            {
                var sChild = src.Children.Single(c => c.FirstChildProp == dChild.FirstChildProp);
                Mapper.Map(sChild, dChild);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This make sense, thank you. I didn't recognize the complexity, being blinded by my isolated case I had.

Comment: A second thought, about the argumentation that AutoMapper can not possibly know about the children in the list etc. Isn't it a little bit awkward that AutoMapper maps FirstChildProp? Seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: @John - behind the scenes, I don't think Automapper is mapping the FirstChildProp **into** the existing SecondClassChild object.  Rather, I expect it is **nuking** SecondClass's `Children` list entirely, and overwriting it with a fresh List of SecondClassChild that it has just created (using `FirstClass.Children` as the mapping source.)  This should become more apparent when the source.Children and dest.Children lists have different lengths.