# Merge two objects using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'd like to merge two objects using AutoMapper (see test below). I've tried a bunch of things but it always copies both properties from the target or the source.

How can I pass the Test below?

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void Merge_people()
{
    var source = new Person() { LastName = "Smith" };
    var target = new Person() { FirstName = "John" };

    Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Person>();
    Mapper.Map(source, target);

    Assert.That(target.FirstName == "John");
    Assert.That(target.LastName == "Smith");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Automapper doesn't yet have that kind of functionality. See link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724901/automapper-merging-values-of-items-in-a-collection-from-one-instance-to-another)

Answer (score 4):

Using properly defined condition you can manage what you need:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Person>()
       .ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((source, destination, member) => member != null));
```

It will map only members that are different than null.
I am using AutoMapper 6.1.1, but I believe it should work for older versions as well.